# Capturing UDID using mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, udid, imei

Is there a way we can capture UDID using mobile browsers.
I have been working on a application  which needs to capture a mobile's UDID/ IMEI information when I'm using the application over my mobile phones and this needs to capture IMEI. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to get a unique identifier such as the UDID or the IMEI on mobile browsers.

If you want to "identify" your users, you will have to use a cookie (but these can be deleted by your user). Another approach which is interesting can be ssen at http://panopticlick.eff.org/ - they "identify" browsers by their capabilities.